# How to get active part from IWorkbenchPage in e4?

Tags: java, e4

The code below is working fine in *e3* but not working in *e4*. I am able to getting active page, but not able to get active part from active page

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage(); 
mpart = (IViewPart) page.getActivePart(); // this line gives null value in e4, but working fine in e3
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be due the eclipse bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=414544.

Try the workaround mentioned in it.

```
    handlerService.getCurrentState().getVariable(ISources.ACTIVE_PART_NAME)
```